# "Need not be" vs. "Need not to be"

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugation

As a native English speaker, I find the phrase "*The hammer need not to be large for...*" sounds strange to my ears.  Instead, I prefer "*The hammer need not be large for...*".  But what is the rule that makes the former grammatically wrong?  Or, maybe I am in error, and indeed the former is technically correct...

Comment: That's because _need_ is a [Semi-Modal auxiliary verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20need%20dare%20semi%20modal), like _dare_, and acts like a modal auxiliary (i.e, no _to_ on infinitive complements) in negative environments. Notice that _The hammer needs to be large_ is grammatical, but not *_The hammer need be large_; that's the way it behaves normally, without a negative around.

Comment: @John: I wouldn't object to `The hammer need be large` in a literary or poetic context.  I would prefer `must`, though.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "need" can function as a linking verb or an action verb. As a linking verb, you can say "need + do" just like you say "can + do" but when it functions as an action verb, an infinite will have to follow "need". That is when you say "need to do something".